# mysql multiple recorded data searching issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table register which have three fields like index `my_caste` `part_caste`

now if i search `part_caste` by id 5 it gives me a single result, but it should give me three results.

how to get three result there:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `FIND_IN_SET()`

```
select * from `register`
where find_in_set(5, part_caste) > 0
```

But you should better change your table design. Never store multiple values in one column!